# Emacs opens file without case-sensitivity and renames it when saving?

Tags: emacs

So I encountered something strange. Say I have a file named `lab01.cpp`. I then open it using `emacs Lab01.cpp`, which will open the file. Then if I edit, save and exit, the file will be renamed to `Lab01.cpp`, which is bad if this accidentally happens.

Is there anyway to prevent this?

Comment: Are you using OSX by chance? OSX filesystem is (usually) case-insensitive.

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: OSX filesystem (called HFS+) will treat Toto, toto and ToTo as the same file. So it's possible that Emacs wants to open Lab01.cpp, HFS+ happily points to lab01.cpp instead. Then, when saving, Emacs moves the original file as a backup (Lab01.cpp~), and stores the buffer into Lab01.cpp, which is what you are getting. This is what makes HFS+ a complete PITA. There is a case sensitive variant, but not by default.

Comment: yeah I am using OSX, that must be the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Juancho points out, this is in part due to the underlying file-system's case insensitivity.  Emacs is/was designed for POSIX where file names are case-sensitive.

In your case, Emacs asks for the file `Lab01.cpp` and the OS happily gives it the `lab01.cpp` file without any indication that it's actually got a different name.

I suspect that `(setq read-file-name-completion-ignore-case t)` will help when you do `C-x C-f Lab01.cpp`  but it probably won't help in your specific use case.

You might `M-x report-emacs-bug` and ask for Emacs to be more careful.